# converting a grid inside a multiview return an empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have this multiview control which contains a grid:

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" ActiveViewIndex="0" runat="server" >
<asp:View ID="View1" runat="server" >
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" RegisterWithScriptManager="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
<MasterTableView>
<Columns>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Name" DataField="NAME"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="LastName" DataField="LASTNAME"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Description" DataField="DESCRIPTION"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
</Columns>
</MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
<asp:Button ID="Navigate" runat="server" OnClick="Navigate_Click" Text="Next" />
</asp:View>
<asp:View ID="View2" runat="server" >

Save your changes 
<asp:Button ID="save" runat="server" OnClick="save_click" Text="Save " />
</asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

Server code :

```
private void convertRadGridTohtml()
{
    StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter SW3 = new StringWriter(SB);
    HtmlTextWriter htmlTW = new HtmlTextWriter(SW3);
    RadGrid1.RenderControl(htmlTW);
    StringWriter oStringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);
    RadGrid1.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
    string html = oHtmlTextWriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
   // toput.InnerHtml = html;
}
```

When the grid is place inside the multiview, the function always return an empty string, but when placed outside the multiview, html object is working fine and it returns the grid as an html.

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems to break when you reference the RadGrid1 directly.Since it is buried in a multiview, locate the active view first and drill down to the grid.Try this

```
  RadGrid  RadGrid1=(RadGrid)MultiView1.Views(1).FindControl("RadGrid1");
  RadGrid1.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
```

This way you are assured that  you are locating the RadGrid1 correctly with its contents.